# C# Deserialize Extended XML Complex types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I've generated code from the schemas available from http://www.gdsregistry.org/3.1/schemas/ using xsd.exe.

I'm trying to deserialize a catalogueItemNofiticationMessage (you can find the XML here: http://www.gs1.se/globalassets/artikelinformation/example-files.zip)

I'm deserializing without any fuss:

```
var cinmSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CatalogueItemNotificationMessageType));
var catalogueItemNotificationMessage = cinmSerializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) as CatalogueItemNotificationMessageType;
```

My problem occurs in the document member of the DocumentCommandType, which doesn't deserialize properly and I just get null.

DocumentCommandType has a DocumentType reference in the schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DocumentCommandType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="documentCommandHeader" type="gdsn_common:DocumentCommandHeaderType" />
        <xsd:element ref="gdsn_common:document" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

CatalogueItemNotificationType extends this type:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CatalogueItemNotificationType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="shared_common:DocumentType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="catalogueItemNotificationIdentification" type="shared_common:EntityIdentificationType" />
                <xsd:element name="isReload" type="xsd:boolean" />
                <xsd:element name="catalogueItem" type="catalogue_item_notification:CatalogueItemType" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The XML file has a documentCommand-element with a catalogueItemNotification.
The inheritance seems to be picked up properly by xsd.exe, as DocumentType has the proper XmlIncludeAttribute:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(CatalogueItemNotificationType))]
[...]
public abstract partial class DocumentType {
```

And the CatalogueItemNotificationType class has the proper inheritance:

```
public partial class CatalogueItemNotificationType : DocumentType
```

But still on deserializing the XML file the document field remains null.

I've tried adding the CatalogueItemNotificationType to the extraTypes parameter of the XmlSerializer constructor, as well as using XmlAttributeOverrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after debugging the xmlserializer.

The serializer didn't have any understanding that the DocumentType[] document field could be anything but the basetype DocumentType.

Adding the following attribute to that property solved it:

```
[XmlElement("catalogueItemNotification", Type = typeof(CatalogueItemNotificationType), Namespace = "urn:gs1:gdsn:catalogue_item_notification:xsd:3")]
```